# Is responsive.desktop.css for desktop & laptops design?

Tags: theming

I am also using the Adaptive theme and same question raised. I checked their documentation, but they do not have point to point instruction.

Its css file has following file,

```
global.base.css
global.styles.css
responsive.custom.css

1. responsive.desktop.css
2. responsive.smalltouch.landscape.css
3. responsive.smalltouch.portrait.css
4. responsive.tablet.landscape.css
5. responsive.tablet.portrait.css
```

1. So, if we see that five different screen size listed in adaptive theme as above, **Do we have to use response.desktop.css for desktop/laptop design or just global.style.css?**
2. Another thing when we see the adaptive theme setting at admin/apperance/ATthem(sub)/setting.....we see three option Standard Layout, Tablet Layout and smalltouch layout....**So Tablet and Smalltouch are understable, they have their own css which means last 4 files, but for standard it is responsive.desktop.css?**

Comment: http://adaptivethemes.com/documentation/css explains it. Global does not target any specific device but loads on all. The other files load individuall via a media query which is not contained in the file individually during development but in production are aggregated. If you want to target all devices use global, otherwise to target for a specific device use accompanying file. Look for the media queries or alternatively resize your browser and see which files are loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll quote from the [adaptive theme documentation](http://adaptivethemes.com/documentation/mobile-first-design-with-adaptivetheme):

> - Global styles always load.
> - Responsive styles load in media queries.

So, you don't need to use **responsive.desktop.css** if you can declare all your styles in **global.style.css**. This is most probably the case if you don't follow the *"mobile first"* approach. But if you do, you probably have additional styles for devices larger than tablets, and that's when responsive.desktop.css comes into play. And of course this is also for laptops. It's the screen size that defines this, not the "wording"...

> **Global Stylesheets**
>
> These load by default. Using a mobile first approach you would only
>   place styles that are going to be used for all devices. You need to be
>   ruthless about this and cut down on what is going into these files -
>   its very easy to assume you will use this or that everwhere, but in
>   reality you are merely falling into the familiar routine of desktop
>   first theming. On your average site these files will be rather small.
>   If they start getting really big, and if you find yourself overriding
>   stuff later in the responsive sheets - then you know you have a
>   problem and need to re-think what you are doing.

[...]

> **Responsive Stylesheets**
>
> Adaptivetheme provides five responsive stylesheets - one for each
>   breakpoint set in your theme settings. During development (see sidebar
>   Development and Production Modes) each of these files is loaded in a
>   link element and places the media query inside the link element
>   itself, as opposed to inside the actual file as an @media declaration.
>   **The media queries are those you set in the Appearance settings for
>   each device type. Adaptivetheme automatically uses these so your
>   styles will match to your layout breakpoints.**

And do not forget about this setting in the theme settings (css):

> **Mobile First or Desktop First** Adaptivetheme supports both mobile first and desktop first design approaches. This setting fundementally
>   alters what CSS is loaded and how it is loaded. At the most basic
>   level if you select Mobile first the Smartphone portrait layout will
>   load as the default, if you select Desktop first the Standard layout
>   will load as the default. Many other changes take place regarding
>   loading of CSS for Internet Explorer, Responsive Gpanels and Panels as
>   well.

Comment: See, your first explanation is completely clear and point-wise when to use what. That kind of explanation needed there in that tutorial documentation. Thanks for clear answer.